# Automatic Instantiation of Reference Type Automatic Properties

Tags: c#, .net

Am I the only person that wants this?  It seems to be something that could reasonably have been provided for any class with a public parameterless constructor.  Now having to instantiate these properties inside the constructor of the class that uses them somewhat obviates the convenience of automatic properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would want to be able to specify the degree of thread safety required. In particular, do you need locking code to be emitted?

Comment: It's probably around this point that the MS team decided not to include this feature. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed that might be useful, but it is what it is. There is no sign of this in C# 4.0, so you'll just have to use either a constructor or a field (and manual property implementation).

Re your "for any class with a public parameterless constructor" - actually, I'd assume that any implementation would be directly comparable to field initializers, so would work regardless of the constructor composition.

Comment: @Marc, good point about the field initializers.  However, my first concern was for types that only expose parametrized constructors: the compiler won't have values for parameters, just as it won't have values for field initializers.